# Launch or compile a Js file via a button in my frontend page html

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I have a js file `batch.js` which do a batch insert for me, but I must launch it from my terminal : `node batch.js`. Now, I want to create a button on my frontend html page, and launch my file via the button.

Comment: This might cover the part where you launch your batch in NodeJS : [Start another node application using node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862214/start-another-node-application-using-node-js)

Comment: Then you'll need to send an AJAX request from your front-end to your server. On the server side, do what @blex points to.

Comment: @MikeC Hii Mike, I didn't get it well, please can you guide me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, per se.

You can use the browser to request a URL (and you can do it from a button by submitting a form), but you need an HTTP server listen to the request for the URL and react accordingly.

Ideally you would rewrite `batch.js` so it was [a module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) and then write a webserver in Node (e.g. using [Express](http://expressjs.com/)) which would load the module and call a function exported from it when the given URL was requested (and then respond to the browser).

More hackily, you would spawn a new instance of node whenever that URL was requested and run your `batch.js` without modification. That would let you use any HTTP server you like and any programming language to write the server side program that would execute `node batch.js`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't get it well, can you give me a a brief example ?

Comment: A brief example of refactoring code I haven't seen into a module, writing a web server in JavaScript, and writing an HTML form? No. That isn't something that can really be covered briefly.