# Need to run a NodeJs application from another NodeJs application

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a NodeJs application running in the following directory

First Application's Path **'/users/user1/projects/sampleProject'** which is running at **3000** port.

Second Application's Path **'/users/user1/demoProjects/demo1'** which is going to run at **5000** port on triggering the router function from first application.

The second NodeJs application is not yet started(It will run at port  5000). It need to run independently on hitting a router function in the first NodeJs Application which is running on port 3000 ie(http://localhost:3000/server/startServer). I'm new to NodeJs child processes, Kindly correct me if i'm wrong. And suggest me a right way to do it. Thanks

[Start another node application using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862214/start-another-node-application-using-node-js)

I have tried it like below

```
// First NodeJs application
import { exec } from "child_process";
router.get('/startServer', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Initiated request")
    let startServerInstance = 'cd "/users/user1/demoProjects/demo1" && npm run dev'; // path for the second NodeJs application
    console.log("Server instance path => " + startServerInstance)
    try {
        // exec from child process, Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell
        let child = exec(startServerInstance, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else {
                console.log("result ")
                res.json({
                    status: 'success'
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            status: 'error',
            message: error
        });
    }    
});
```

The above code executes the command and triggered the second application to run in background but it doesn't return anything. Either error or success result.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about why you want to do this?  It seems rather unorthodox.  See also [What is the X Y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/102937)

Comment: Also, you can't `await` a function that will return a result into a callback (well, you can, but it wouldn't work as you expects)

Comment: which version of node do you are using?

Comment: @Manuel Spigolon, node - 8.10.0, npm - 5.6.0

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm trying to develop a cryptocurrency wallet application, in which i need to simulate a separate instance for each user for demo purpose.

Comment: @RidgeA, yes you are right, i have removed it so.

Comment: `stdout` may provide more pertinent information than `err` will. I'd suggest looking into the values of `stdout` when the command both succeeds and fails and key off that

Comment: @Zenkylo, correct but it had never returned anything either error or success result. But in the background, when i tried to run the port 5000, It runs. If the second application ran means then it might have returned something, In my case it doesn't

Comment: The callback function is only called once the process terminates. If your child process remains running the callback is not triggered.

Comment: @KVNam yes, callback Called with the output when process terminates. If thats the case i cannot run my server instance independently. if i terminate it, then it will stop the second application's server instance which is not right as per my task.

Comment: @Jeeva Yes. I'm not sure what your exact case is, but you will need to find a way to trigger process termination based on some condition, in order to access the result.

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments @KVNam, i will go through the nodejs child processes  document again.

Comment: @Jeeva Glad I could help, I've added the answer below with a link to the child process documentation. Would appreciate it if you could mark it as the answer.

Comment: What if we process a bash script that runs the second node instance. For example, `exec('./someBashScript', (err, stdout, stderr) {...}`

The bash script would run the second instance, for example;
`#!/usr/bin/bash
node/users/user1/demoProjects/demo1.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `stout` and `stderror` to check other server logs. Also your code is not correct. If you use `if` without `{}` it will not go to `else` statement. That is why you don't see 'result' text in console.

```
import {
    exec
} from "child_process";
router.get('/startServer', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Initiated request")
    let startServerInstance = 'cd "/users/user1/demoProjects/demo1" && npm run dev'; // path for the second NodeJs application
    console.log("Server instance path => " + startServerInstance)
    try {
        // exec from child process, Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell
        let child = exec(startServerInstance, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Server started");
        });

        child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            // this is new server output
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            // this is new server error output
            console.log(data.toString());
        });

        res.json({
            status: 'success'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            status: 'error',
            message: error
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How is this working for you? I thought `stdout` and `stderr` are of either string or buffer type, containing the output from the child process and not in fact pipes. I'm getting an error when I try this.

Comment: @hurricane, Thank you for your answer, Now I can able to see the data events

Answer (score 1):

Child process callback is only called once the process terminates. If the process keeps running, callback is not triggered.

Explained here - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Hi KVNam, I have tried the below scenario. The callback is called once the process terminates. eg. replaced the **let startServerInstance = 'cd "/users/user1/demoProjects/demo1" && npm run dev';** with **let startServerInstance = 'mkdir -p ./testDir'**. It had created the folder. Hence the process is completed and i got the response. But in my case, its an ever running process. so i manually killed the port after it ran. By this time it might have fired the callback so the process is complete by killing it, but i didnt get any response

Comment: The corrected answer given by @hurricane below is the right way to capture stdout data from a running process. The `child` variable which holds the ChildProcess instance, can be used to watch for `data` events. This is outside the callback so you don't have to wait for the process to terminate. There is a `message` event as well which you can check out.